# JavaScript Best Practices: How to implement long-lived apps (one-page web apps)?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Are there any best practices for implementing a long-lived JavaScript app, i.e. a web app that consists of a single page and loads other pages into the content area via AJAX? (Gmail is a good example of this.)

I already read about pro and cons, SEO, performance, etc. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499129/one-page-only-javascript-applications), I'm interested in patterns how to implement this.

I'd like to avoid large frameworks (e.g. Cappuccino, Echo2, SproutCore, Claypool).

How would I manage dynamically loading content while maintaining the #link portion of the URL (for bookmarking)?

Don't get me wrong, I have an idea how to implement this myself, but this problem must have been solved before.

Are there articles on this? Maybe a tiny JavaScript library?

Thanks!
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found JQuery Address http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ extremely easy to set up. `$.address.change()` let's you know whenever something was clicked (works with back and forth as well) and you just parse `self.location.hash` and build your app from there. It seems lighweight enough as well, if you can handle using JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article to help you with the History bookmarks problem: http://codinginparadise.org/weblog/2005/09/ajax-dhtmlhistory-and-historystorage.html. It's quite old, but the solution still works.

I made several apps using this "long lived" apps, and one thing you should take into account is IE's tendency to leak memory.

I would also recommend you to use a JS library, like JQuery to help you with the AJAX and DHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Heard about javascript pushstate?

http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate

It's meant to replace location.hash

Comment: An HTML5 only solution does not (yet) work for me. However, the jQuery BBQ plugin linked from that site seems to offer what I need: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/ (#location state management)